# Java generics: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a template `HashTable` which can store any type of records. I am using Java generics to do the same. Following is the code snippet from the `HashTable`:

```
class MyHashTable <T, K>{

    private int size;
    private Vector <Vector <T>> table;

    public MyHashTable(int s) {
        size = s;
        table = new Vector(size);
    }

    void insert(T newRecord) {
        int hash = newRecord.getHash(size);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Folowing is an example of the type of record that I want to store:

```
class Record {

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getKey() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHash(int hash_table_size) {
        int index = 0;
        String key = getKey();
        for(int i=0; i<key.length(); i++)
            index += (int)key.charAt(i);
        index = index % hash_table_size;
        return index;
    }
    ...
}
```

To instantiate the HashTable, I write:

```
MyHashTable <Record, String> hashTable = new MyHashTable(50);
```

When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
HashTableImplementation.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
int hash = newRecord.getHash(size);
                            ^
symbol:   method getHash(int)
location: variable newRecord of type T
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class MyHashTable
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need: `T extends Record` in `class MyHashTable <T, K> {`, as the `newRecord` is defined of type `T` which in no way relates to `Record` currently. Thus it fails to identify that it has the method `getHash`.

Comment: Thank you all. As @Aubin mentioned I had to create an abstract class CHashable (instead of an interface as it gives me a compilation error). I made Record class extend CHashable and it stopped giving me the symbol not found errors. However, I am still curious as to why we are not allowed to write class MyHashTable <T implements IHashable> (where IHashable is an interface) just as we write class MyHashTable <T extends CHashable>. I got syntax error saying '>'/'{' is missing when I tried to do that.

Comment: You can write <T extends IHashable>, even when IHashable is an interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your definition to

```
class MyHashTable <T extends Record, K>
```

**or** do similar on a method level

```
<T extends Record> void insert(T newRecord) {
    int hash = newRecord.getHash(size);
}
```

By adding the bounded parameter you're instructing that you're accepting only the type of *Record* or its subtypes. And you need to use it as you're calling a method specific to the *Record* class against your parametrized type

Comment: IMHO: better with an interface `IHashable`, `Record implements IHashable`

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a generic class

```
class MyHashTable <T, K>{
```

with a type parameter `T`. This type parameter is unbounded, so, at runtime, any reference type can be bound to it.

But here

```
void insert(T newRecord) {
    int hash = newRecord.getHash(size);
    ...
}
```

you are assuming that `newRecord` will be of type `Record` and will have a `newRecord` method. This is a false assumption.

Answer (score 0):

No, your relies on a hash code for collision detection in the hash table. So you need your object to implement hashCode function .. Which is defined in the Java spec. So change 'getHash' to 'hashCode' and should be OK and behave as expected

D